# PHP - Suppress PDF META Data when outputting via Header

Tags: php, pdf, meta

I have a simple PHP page that reads the content of a PDF by using file_get_contents and proceeds to output it using headers

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=".$row["FILsFileName"]);

The problem is that I need to remove some META information that looks like it appears as the raw content as:

```
     <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt>
           <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">TITLE HERE</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
     </dc:title>
```

Is there a way to override this title? I've tried doing a str_replace, but Acrobat seems to feel that it makes it an invalid PDF.

Can this be easily overriden when streaming it?